# Ember CLI import ES6 file to ember-cli-builds.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-classic

So the ember-cli-builds.js file clearly states

```
// If the library that you are including contains AMD or ES6
// modules that you would like to import into your application
// please specify an object with the list of modules as keys
// along with the exports of each module as its value.
```

I'm importing regular javascript files this way

```
app.import('vendor/global.js');
```

but what is the proper way to "specify an object with the list of modules as keys along with the exports of each module as it's value"?

Comment: Have you tried `app.import({
    "global": app.import('vendor/global.js')
    // etc
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the "AMD Javascript modules" heading of the guides, it is described like that:

> Provide the asset path as the first argument, and the list of modules
>   and exports as the second.
>
> ```
> app.import('bower_components/ic-ajax/dist/named-amd/main.js', {
>   exports: {
>     'ic-ajax': [
>       'default',
>       'defineFixture',
>       'lookupFixture',
>       'raw',
>       'request'
>     ]
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> You can now `import` them in your app. (e.g. `import { raw as icAjaxRaw } from 'ic-ajax';`)

Reference [From Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/#toc_amd-javascript-modules)

Comment: Thank you @ykaragol

Answer (score 0):

The selector answer is for older ember, pre ember-auto-import (webpack), and pre Ember Octane.

In modern ember, after `npm install`ing a package, you'll be able to import directly from that package.

Example:

```
npm install qs
```

then anywhere in your app

```
import qs from 'qs';
```

related, it is recommended to avoid placing files in the vendor folder that you want to integrate with the module system. the vendor exists outside of the bundle, so if you have a standalone module, you can place it in your `app` folder, maybe under some descriptive folder:
`app/external-modules/global.js`, allowing you to import from it like:

```
import * as globalStuff from '<my-app>/external-modules/global';
```